# How to compare individuals through two paths in SHACL?

Tags: rdf, owl, shacl, topbraid-composer

This questions is related to the one [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68518850/multiple-paths-and-existential-quantification-in-shacl-rules-should-i-use-shon). Let's say it is an "extended question".

The ontology at that link contains the following individuals:

```
:a rdf:type :Approve ;
   :has-theme :r1,:r2 .

:r1 rdf:type :Result ;
    :come-from :m1 .

:r2 rdf:type :Result ;
    :come-from :m2 .

:m1 rdf:type :Man .
:m2 rdf:type :Machine .
```

Now I have added the following triples to the ontology:

```
:a :has-agent :x .
:m1 :friend-of :x .
```

That is: ":x is the agent of the Approve action :a" and ":m1 is friend of :x".

In the question at the link above, I wanted to write a SHACL rule stating that "Every Approve action having among its themes at least a Result that comes from a Man is Legal".

And Holger suggested me to use the following condition (antecedent) of the SHACL rule. The condition works (thanks Holger!):

```
    :conditionTest
        rdf:type sh:NodeShape ;
        sh:property [
            sh:path (ontology:has-theme ontology:come-from) ;
            sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
            sh:qualifiedValueShape [
                sh:class ontology:Man ;
            ]
        ] .
```

Now I want to extend the conditions above fit to obtain the following extended SHACL rule: "Every Approve action having among its themes at least a Result that comes from a Man ***who is friend of the Approve action's agent*** is Legal".

Basically: I want to start from the Approve action ":a", take its agent from one path, take the friends of the men producing results as theme of ":a" from another path... and compare the pairs of individuals through these paths, i.e., asking them when they match.

I tried to extend the :conditionTest above in several ways, e.g., with sh:equals:

```
    :conditionTest
        rdf:type sh:NodeShape ;
        sh:property [
            sh:path (ontology:has-theme ontology:come-from) ;
            sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
            sh:qualifiedValueShape [
                sh:class ontology:Man ;
                sh:property [
                    sh:path ontology:friend-of;
                    sh:equals [sh:property [sh:path (sh:this ontology:has-agent)]]
                ]
            ]
        ] .
```

But no solution I tried works. On the other hand, if I use sh:hasValue and I explicitly mention the individual :x, i.e.:

```
    :conditionTest
        rdf:type sh:NodeShape ;
        sh:property [
            sh:path (ontology:has-theme ontology:come-from) ;
            sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
            sh:qualifiedValueShape [
                sh:class ontology:Man ;
                sh:property [
                    sh:path ontology:friend-of;
                    sh:hasValue ontology:x
                ]
            ]
        ] .
```

It works. But this is not actually what I want: a want a SHACL rule that works for *any* individual as has-agent of :a. In other words: I want to get&compare this individual through the path "(sh:this has-agent)".

Hope any of you knows a way to do it.
Thanks in advance.
Livio

Comment: This gets complex and you may be better off formulating this using SPARQL rules, esp if you need to make joins between specific values: https://w3c.github.io/shacl/shacl-af/#SPARQLRule

Comment: Ok... I wanted to avoid SPARQL rules, but if that's the only way, I will. Thanks!